# puzzle: really simple vlookup not working

Tags: excel, vlookup

Really simple sheet.
See screenshot.

The VLookup Formula I am using is also shown in the screenshot is:
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(D3),A2:B5,2)

car give price
truck gives price
boat gives:  #N/A    (there are no spaces before or after boat; when I stick cursor in there on cell A4, it is blinking at the end of 't' in boat)
how to fix?

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: 4th param = false

Comment: VLOOKUP(TRIM(D3),A2:B5,2, FALSE) -means do not use binary lookup. b comes before car, and therefore it is deemed n/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula. Adding FALSE will make it look for an exact match:

```
=VLOOKUP(D3,A2:B5,2,FALSE)
```